# Javascript code for focusing on a certain div after loading the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a page horizontally and my problem is, and it starts from the end(DIVs are defined in right-to-left order, and it shows the one which is on the left)
I need a function to tell the browser to focus on the right div onload,so the user won't get confused.
thank you.
s.rb

Comment: What you have tried.

Comment: Show us your code before we can help you.

Answer (score 4):

By focus I assume you mean you want to scroll to the correct div on load.

if the div was defined like:

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

you can scroll to it in javascript with:

```
window.location.hash = '#main';
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

Set `tabIndex` to the element which you want to focus.

**HTML**

```
<div id = "iWillBFocused">
 I will be focused on referesh 
</div>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById('iWillBFocused').focus()
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/52tynebn/1/)

Answer (score 0):

**Vanilla JS**

There is a focus function that can be called on an html element:

`document.querySelector('#myElement').focus();`

You can read more about it on the [Mozilla Documentation site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus).

**jQuery**

If you're using jQuery, you can also use the built-in jQuery `focus()` method:

`$('#myElement').focus();`